# Odd wake on lan issue over a specific port

Tags: windows, networking, wake-on-lan

I'm at a loss on where to go from a troubleshooting standpoint.  I want to use a software called [Multiplicity](https://www.stardock.com/products/multiplicity/) to handle my KVM duties, as well as my wake on lan duties.   Until i purchased said software, I used a combination of a UWP app called [Wake-On-Lan(Magic Packet)](https://www.depicus.com/wake-on-lan/wake-on-lan-gui) and [Teamviewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/) to handle the same functions.

The problem is, I cannot wake anything up from my main pc but ONLY with multiplicity.  Teamviewer will (unsure if it uses a magic packet or something proprietary related to their cloud set up as it doesn't require a mac, just a teamviewerID).   The UWP app will as well with the Mac address and a choice of port (only allows you 7 or 9)

Multiplicity on the other hand uses an obscure port (developers said it was 30564).  No idea why the deviation from the standard, but nonetheless - it wont work.

I've tried from a clean boot.  I've tried with Windows Firewall off on both machines.  Craziest part?  It works from either of the other two machines.

I used wake on lan monitor on my second pc and it's not getting the packet.  I have no idea what my next step is to see where the hang up is at.

How may I troubleshoot this further to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out running `Get-NetIPInterface` from powershell showed my virtualbox adapter having the same metric as my Ethernet adapter.   Increasing the metric with `Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceIndex 17 -InterfaceMetric 85` was enough to right it.  Phew!